# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in rspec but not in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, rspec

I'm using Spree E-commerce at the moment. I've written my own extension and actually I'm able to call in console this:

```
hash = 
     {:email=>"test@2.pl",
         :password=>"123123123",
         :password_confirmation=>"123123123",
         :profile_attributes=>
          {:first_name=>"zdziski",
           :last_name=>"fdfdi",
           :position=>"dev",
           :address_attributes=>
            {"firstname"=>"Pal",
             "lastname"=>"Zdzski",
             "address1"=>"Kakaka",
             "address2"=>"",
             "city"=>"Bszcz",
             "country_id"=>"72",
             "zipcode"=>"323232",
             "phone"=>"633336594"}}}
```

and then

```
u = Spree::User.create(hash)
```

and have possitive response! awesome! But problem appears when I'm calling this in my rspec

```
attributes = { email: "test@2.pl", password: "123123123", password_confirmation: "123123123", profile_attributes: { first_name:"pawel",last_name:"zmudzinski", position:"lol", address_attributes: {"firstname"=>"Pawel", "lastname"=>"Zmudzinski", "address1"=>"Kakaka", "address2"=>"", "city"=>"Bydgoszcz", "country_id"=>"72", "zipcode"=>"323232", "phone"=>"323432432"}  }}
```

and then

`expect { Spree::User.create(attributes)}.to change { Spree::Address.count }.by(1)`

or

```
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user,profile_attributes: { first_name:"pawel",last_name:"zmudzinski", position:"lol", address_attributes: {"firstname"=>"Pawel", "lastname"=>"Zmudzinski", "address1"=>"Kakaka", "address2"=>"", "city"=>"Bydgoszcz", "country_id"=>"72", "zipcode"=>"323232", "phone"=>"1234325432"}  })
```

response in consol is:

```
Failure/Error: expect { Spree::User.create(attributes)}.to change { Spree::Address }.by(1)
 ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
   unknown attribute: user_profile_id
```

what's now? why does it works in rails console but not in spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the profile_attributes a part of your extension - because your console stuff does not prove that your code could create an address, just a user. Is your extension somewhere on Github for us to try?

Comment: unfortunately I'm not able to share source code of it... Actually this console code create all user , profile and address model (all are associated with eachother)

Comment: IN the error you don't have a line number indicating where the error occurs?